# How to resolve error where Mac is not configured in way compatible with macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, upgrade, catalina

I get the following when trying to install macOS Catalina (from High Sierra):

[image]

I contacted Apple Support, reset my whole system to factory settings and yet I cannot update.

it is MacBook Pro 2017 without Touch Bar and I bought it seal packed 2 years ago

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that your Mac is configured in a non-standard way? What OS are you on? What model of Mac?

Comment: Also: what did Apple Support propose to do? And if you tried and it didn't help, did you get back to them?

Comment: it is MacBook Pro 2017 without Touch Bar and I bought it seal packed 2 years ago.

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: I am on High Sierra

Comment: Are you attempting to upgrade fro High Sierra to Catalina or are you doing a fresh install?

Comment: I am attempting to upgrade from high Sierra to Catalina also before this I had Mojave and it gave the same error when I clicked the installer

Comment: Don't know why this is happening and this error is nowhere else on the web

Comment: Try a clean install.  And just out of curiosity, did you get this Mac from Apple (or an authorized seller) or someone else who claimed it was new?  I’ve seen macOS throw some weird errors on Macs sourced from questionable sellers.

Comment: Recovery Mode while holding COMMAND-OPTION-R at startup is *supposed* to allow you to select the latest compatible version of the macOS on your Mac. Have you tried that? It would be beneficial for you to indicate **everything** you have done to get this far.

Comment: I have done everything from recovery mode to downloading the installer from App Store to resetting my Mac